# Transaction on objects in C#

Tags: c#, transactions, object, rollback

I was wondering if there is a way to have a transaction on object.
I'm asking this question for the following situation:

We pass our object to our dataaccesslayer. There we use transactionscope to make sure the database doesn't get corrupted.

In that process an object can be changed (datechanged, owner, ect ...). But if the transaction fails the transactionscope rollbacks the transactions in the database but not on your object.

This way your object (which is passed by reference) is kinda corrupted.

I hope there is a solution for this.

Comment: similar question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765615/transactions-for-c-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about this 
[Transactions for C# objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765615/transactions-for-c-objects)

Answer (score 2):

When you use TransactionScope, it will explicitly tell you when it rolls back (by giving you an error). If this happens, you shouldn't continue to process on your object until you've got it clean from its source.

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt you can have transaction on your class objects. Maybe you could customize your code to maintain the state in another instance and restore it just after your rollback statement.

Answer (score 0):

I you use a good OR-Mapper like NHibernate instead of a custom data layer, this will be taken care for you